# Having trouble coming up with a method to implement data into a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable that needs to be populated with the data from a function.

This datatable has 4 columns

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("DataTable");
table.Add("Header1", typeof(string));
table.Add("Header2", typeof(string));
table.Add("Header3", typeof(string));
table.Add("Header4", typeof(string));
```

This function returns 4 lists of strings

```
(List<string> list1, 
 List<string> list2,
 List<string> list3, 
 List<string> list4) = await class.function();
```

I need to loop through these 4 lists and add the data from them into the datatable like so

```
table.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3, value4);
```

The problem is I can only loop through one list at a time like so

```
foreach (string value in list1)
{
    table.Rows.Add(value);
}
```

How can I loop through all 4 list simultaneously and add the data to the datatable?

Comment: From where you are getting these values: value1, value2, value3, value4?

Comment: Those are just sample values, that is how I would like to add my data into the datatable as there are four columns that need to be filled out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your lists have the same Count, you could use the [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx) of each  `List<string>` instance.

```
for(int i=0; i < list1.Count; i++) 
{
    table.Rows.Add(list1[i], list2[i], list3[i], list4[i]);
}
```

but this will break if the list's have different counts.

If your lists have different counts but you want to fill the table up to the last available field in any of those list you can happily over-engineer a class to do that.

The following class takes any number of lists in its constructor and then let you iterate over all those lists util they have all run out. Basically this class calls the MoveNext on each lists enumerator until it returns false. As it implements an enumerator itself, it returns an object[] to could go into a DataTable.Rows.Add.

```
// enumerate any number of lists and return an object[] for each index
public class MultiListIterator: IEnumerator<object[]>, IEnumerable<object[]>, IEnumerable
{
    readonly List<IEnumerator> lists = new List<IEnumerator>();
    public MultiListIterator(params IEnumerable[] lst)
    {
       Array.ForEach(lst , (item) => lists.Add(item.GetEnumerator()));
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
       return this;
    }

    // generic enumerator
    public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
    {
       return this;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        bool any = false;
        // keep track of which are completed
        var completed = new List<IEnumerator>();
        foreach(var list in lists)
        {
            if (list != null) 
            {
                var move = list.MoveNext();
                any = any || move;
                if (!move) completed.Add(list);
            }
        }
        // nullify the completed iterators
        foreach(var nullitem in completed)
        {
            lists[lists.IndexOf(nullitem)] = null;
        }
        return any;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current 
    {
        get 
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    // generic Enumerator
    public object[] Current 
    {
        get 
        {
            object[] result = new object[lists.Count];
            for(int i=0; i<lists.Count; i++) 
            {
                if (lists[i] != null)
                {
                    result[i] = lists[i].Current;
                } 
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void Reset() 
    {
    }
    public void Dispose() 
    {
    }  
}
```

Here is how you would use that class with 4 lists but it can take any number of lists if you want.

```
foreach(var row in new MultiListIterator(list1, list2, list3, list4))
{
   // row returns an object[] 
   dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Here is an example output with 4 lists and an unequal count between those lists:

[image: mulitlistiterator]

Comment: Thankyou, my lists all have the same amount of values in them - I didn't think to do something like this